# OvenMediaEngine Answer Sdp parsing error: a=group:LS locQqN

Tags: c++, webrtc, video-streaming, nlohmann-json, libdatachannel

I cannot connect to OvenMediaEngine server with a libdatachannel library. When I send answer message it returns `Could not parse SDP` error. I can't find true format of answer type message.

I sent request offer with:

```
{"command", "request_offer"}
```

Response:

```
{"candidates":[{"candidate":"candidate:9845236701 1 UDP 50 192.168.xx.xx 10001 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0},{"candidate":"candidate:8725610493 1 UDP 50 1xx.xx.0.1 10001 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0}],"code":200,"command":"offer","id":508901731,"peer_id":0,"sdp":{"sdp":"v=0\r\no=OvenMediaEngine 101 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE locQqN\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS FrzS2IOoXH0GTmc93hD7njBQwtJ15CPNKRMu\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 AA:11:19:C1:60:07:5A:C6:xx:xx:D3:A1:5D:4C:C3:44:C2:59:F6:09:88:36:79:13:73:34:C9:F8:12:E3:8B:47\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=ice-ufrag:3ieW7O\r\na=ice-pwd:wY0yg2pcLTths19xUZ5PGfAk7XjiClQN\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=sendonly\r\na=mid:locQqN\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=msid:FrzS2IOoXH0GTmc93hD7njBQwtJ15CPNKRMu c3Q4JeTvx29WAi7btFaSR6dZsrLnjIoMCuzE\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:framemarking\r\na=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=rtpmap:98 H264/90000\r\na=fmtp:98 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=ssrc:2526952431 cname:1AThzs46gkvOHrDS\r\na=ssrc:2526952431 msid:FrzS2IOoXH0GTmc93hD7njBQwtJ15CPNKRMu c3Q4JeTvx29WAi7btFaSR6dZsrLnjIoMCuzE\r\na=ssrc:2526952431 mslabel:FrzS2IOoXH0GTmc93hD7njBQwtJ15CPNKRMu\r\na=ssrc:2526952431 label:c3Q4JeTvx29WAi7btFaSR6dZsrLnjIoMCuzE\r\n","type":"offer"}}
```

I create answer message:

```
{"command":"answer","id":508901731,"peer_id":0,"sdp":{"sdp":"v=0\r\no=rtc 2314657025 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE locQqN\r\na=group:LS locQqN\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\na=setup:active\r\na=ice-ufrag:hptN\r\na=ice-pwd:Ai0Bb1M+FufKdPNsatTQ6z\r\na=ice-options:ice2,trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 2B:A0:66:23:E9:74:AE:98:50:xx:xx:xx:EF:8C:DA:41:AA:8A:96:2C:C6:9B:C6:0B:EC:FA:B5:DF:E7:95:D7:BB\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=mid:locQqN\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:framemarking\r\na=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=recvonly\r\na=msid:FrzS2IOoXH0GTmc93hD7njBQwtJ15CPNKRMu c3Q4JeTvx29WAi7btFaSR6dZsrLnjIoMCuzE\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:98 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=fmtp:98 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1\r\n","type":"answer"}}
```

Response:

```
{"code":400,"error":"Could not parse SDP"}
```

I saw this error message on the server:

> ```
> [2023-04-03 17:23:44.946] E [SPRtcSig-t15000:1439483] Signalling | rtc_signalling_server.cpp:410  | An error occurred while dispatch command answer for stream [#default#app/stream3]: [HTTP] Could not parse SDP (400), disconnecting...
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Json::LogicError'
> what():  in Json::Value::find(begin, end): requires objectValue or nullValue
> [2023-04-03 17:23:44.946] C [SPRtcSig-t15000:1439483] OvenMediaEngine | signals.cpp:114  | OME received signal 6 (SIGABRT), interrupt.
> ```

I tried different types of answer messages but the result didn't change. When I try wrong JSON format server down. I can't find the message format for answer.
[This link](https://airensoft.gitbook.io/ovenmediaengine/streaming/webrtc-publishing) has ostensibly figured out the include message format but it didn't work.

Does anyone know format of answer message or is it my fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with OvenMediaEngine, so please take this with a grain of salt.

I would start the investigation by noticing that your offer contains only BUNDLE group attribute (all streams are bundled over the same socket). In your case, you only have a video stream, so that is redundant but definitely not wrong.

However, your answer contains two groups: BUNDLE and LS. BUNDLE is ok because the offer had it, but I question whether the answer can contain a group not listed in the offer. Can you just remove

> a=group:LS locQqN

from your answer and see what happens. Incidentally, LS is for lipsync and you only have one video stream, so lipsync is not useful here.

See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3388/ 8.4.1, which says that

> ...grouping requests are always performed by offerers, not by answerers

Comment: I remove lip sync from sdp. Error gone thank you.